# Convert x y coordinates to polyline shapefile

Tags: convert, polyline-creation, ascii, text, xy

I am trying to process output from a model that simulates the movement of particles in groundwater. The program outputs the particle ID number, the x and y coordinates, and the time at which the particle is at those specific coordinates.
Each line contains the ID, X, Y, and T. For example:

No_1......2.34546E+03......7.73783E+03......1.20647E+04
No_2......5.37637E+03......8.52437E+03......1.37673E+04
No_1......2.37357E+03......7.74387E+03......1.21567E+04

There are hundreds of particles and each particle has several hundred x,y,t values.  The file sizes can easily be over 100GB.  I can sort/group the file so that each particle is listed in order of increasing travel time.

Is there a way to convert a text file with these coordinates into a shapefile that contains one continuous polyline for each particle, from its first x,y location to its final x,y location?  I'm not going to do anything with the polylines other than display them, so the attributes aren't really important.  I don't have a need to identify or select them based on particle ID, for example.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: The groundwater model is MODPATH. I could use python or perl to post-process the output.  I've checked into the available python and perl GIS modules/libraries, but nothing seemed to be able to do what I want.

Comment: Perhaps create a point shapefile in Arc based on the coordinates, then use the "Points to Line" tool. For the Line Field parameter specify the ID field, for the Sort Field parameter specify the T field. This should create one line for each ID and connect the points based on the ascending time stamps.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS with plugin Points2One seems to be the a good fit.

1. Convert your text files to point shapefile

Layer/Add layer/Add delimited text layer

2. Use Points2One to convert to lines:

[image]

I'm not sure though how it will handle 100Gb file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I work in ArcGIS, so my workflow would be to parse the data into a table with "From" and "To" coordinate pairs. I would keep the attributes, particularly the model layer.

I think that a better solution would be to find existing software that can export the path lines. The help for MODPATH version 6 seems to say that you can use MODPATH Examiner to export the path lines, quote: "Model grid and particle output data (such as endpoints, pathlines, and timeseries points) can be exported as shapefiles."
http://pubs.usgs.gov/tm/6a41/pdf/TM_6A_41.pdf page 58.

EDIT: I learned in the comments that we need to be able to convert MODPATH output files to lines without using groundwater modeling software. I tested a manual conversion of a MODPATH paths file (ptl) to lines in ArcGIS. First I opened a ptl file in a text editor and deleted the header. I parsed the ptl file (in MS Access), added column headings, and loaded the table in a geodatabase. Next I used a suggestion from Nir (in the comments) to run "Points to Line" on an event layer posted from the table. It only took me a few minutes, but my ptl file only had a few hundred thousand points.

Comment: I've tried both Groundwater Vistas and MODPATH Examiner, but they cannot handle the large file sizes.

Comment: Everything starts with a table. As you showed in your example, MODPATH outputs space-delimited ascii files with xyz fields and an ID field. I think that the path lines file has an extension of .ptl. Unfortunately, ArcGIS does not read space-delimited files, so you have to parse them in python. Do you have a table yet? I think that the rest should be fairly easy.